Sending a single transaction through Jito using Python
Is it possible to send single transactions through Jito (and including a tip) using Python?
If yes, any ideas on how it can be done and how should the tip be included in the instructions of the sendTransaction request in order to be picked up by a Jito validator? I guess that the sendTransaction request should be sent to https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf?

You can use their python sdk
or use their transaction proxy at https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions
just add a tip via a transfer instruction to one of their tip accounts (see the SDK)
the bundle id will be on the response headers

Did you find any solution or how to? I am trying to send my transaction with tip   to https://mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf/api/v1/transactions, I get transaction signature but it's empy. It does not last even with error. There is no any log related to signature.
